# Criar relatório exibindo total e subtotal

Tags: php, mysql

Estou precisando criar um relatório em PHP no qual as informações serão buscadas no MySQL.

No MySQL eu tenho uma lista de boleto emitidos, no qual a maioria foi quitado.
Nesta tabela(Historico) possui o seguintes campos:

- Código_Boleto
- Código_Cliente
- Data_Pagamento
- Valor_Pago
- Grupo_Financeiro

Gostaria que o relatório exibisse todos os dados, mas separando as empresas por grupo e calculando o subtotal arrecadado de cada grupo(São vários grupos).

Exemplo:

```
GRUPO-1

 1. Cliente1   |   26/02/2018   |   100,00   |   Grupo1
 2. Cliente7   |   22/02/2018   |    50,00   |   Grupo1  
 3. Cliente8   |   10/02/2018   |    50,00   |   Grupo1 

Subtotal = 200,00

GRUPO-2

 1. Cliente3   |   01/02/2018   |   120,00   |   Grupo2
 2. Cliente5   |   01/02/2018   |    40,00   |   Grupo2  
 3. Cliente9   |   11/02/2018   |    50,00   |   Grupo2 

Subtotal = 210,00

Total Final = 410,00
```

Não estou encontrando a lógica ideal para geara automaticamente desta forma.
Poderiam me ajudar?

Comment: O que você já fez? quer que o SQL traga tudo pronto ou pode ser formatado no PHP?

Comment: Gulherme, já fiz toda parte gráfica do relatório, mas a principal (PHP e MySQL) ainda não. Estou utilizando o Codeigniter, mas não vou me apegar ao detalhe do framework.... Quero fazer da forma que sobrecarregue menos o servidor, ou seja, da forma mais correta possível.

Comment: Não uso nenhum framework PHP, mas eu faria (sem Codeigniter) uma busca SQL pegando todos os dados sem `WHERE`, ordenando por grupo e cliente, dividiria a tela em varias tabelas (1 por grupo), total e subtotal eu deixaria para o JS calcular

Comment: Sim, mas minha dúvida é como fazer para separar por grupo.
Não quero imprimir tudo junto entendeu? E ficaria muito pesado fazer um while para cada grupo...

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar o DISTINCT do SQL, ele pega todos os valores de uma tabele, e pega 1 único exemplo de cada.

```
Table (User):
User | Empresa

A     | Google
B     | Facebook
C     | Google
D     | Facebook
```

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT empresa FROM User
```

Retorno:

```
    Google
    Facebook
```

Perceba que ele retornou todos os tipos de empresa só uma vez.

Com outras duas consultas, você pode pegar os usuários e a soma total.

```sql
SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE Grupo = 'NOME_GRUPO'

SELECT SUM(COLUMN_PRICE) FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE Grupo = 'NOME_GRUPO';
```

Esse é um método que ele pede mais consultas, porem retorna pequenos resultados, e quem processa tudo é o banco de dados.

Você poderia usar método para ordenar, passar valor por valor somando, e quando chegar em um grupo diferente, ele coloca o máximo e começa a somar de novo. Mas dai usuário o processamento do servidor que está rodando o server de PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode fazer algo assim (mysqli, sem Codeigniter):

Só para entender, primeiro é guardado o valor do primeiro grupo e sempre que ele muda a tabela é fechada, mostra o total e abre uma nova, depois calcula o total geral pelo js

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', 'costamilam', 'teste');

$sql = "
    SELECT 
        *
    FROM 
        a
    ORDER BY
        grupo_financeiro,
        codigo_cliente
";

$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql);

$stmt->execute();

$resultado = $stmt->get_result();

$array = $resultado->fetch_all();

?>
<table>
    <thead>
        <th>
            <td>Cliente</td>
            <td>Data</td>
            <td>Valor</td>
        </th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

<?php
$total = 0;
$grupo = $array[0][4];

foreach($array as $a) {
    if($grupo == $a[4]) {
        $total += $a[3];

        echo "
            <tr>
                <td>$a[1]</td>
                <td>$a[2]</td>
                <td>$a[3]</td>
            </tr>
        ";
    } else {
        $grupo = $a[4];

        echo "
                </tbody>
                <tfoot>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Total R$<span class='total'>$total</td>
                    </tr>
                </tfoot>
            </table>

            <table>
                <thead>
                    <th>
                        <td>Cliente</td>
                        <td>Data</td>
                        <td>Valor</td>
                    </th>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>$a[1]</td>
                        <td>$a[2]</td>
                        <td>$a[3]</td>
                    </tr>
        ";

        $total = $a[3];
    }
}
?>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <td>Total R$<span class='total'><?php echo $total; ?></td>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>

<p id="total"></p>

<script>
    var texto = document.getElementById('total')

    var totais = document.getElementsByClassName('total')

    var total = 0

    for(var i = 0; i < totais.length; i++) {
        total += parseInt(totais[i].firstChild.nodeValue)
    }

    texto.innerText = 'TOTAL GERAL: R$' + total
</script>
```