# Exibir produtos de várias categorias

Tags: php, mysql, relacionamento

Essa é minha primeira postagem, estou tentando resolver um problema há algum tempo já, porém sem sucesso.

Tenho a tabela CATEGORIAS e a tabela PRODUTOS

Preciso exibir da seguinte maneis:

CATEGORIA 1

```
- Produto 1
- Produto 2
```

CATEGORIA 2

```
- Produto 1
- Produto 2
```

Estou fazendo da seguinte maneira (APENAS UM EXEMPLO)

```
$var = SELECT * FROM categorias INNER JOIN produtos ON categorias.id = produtos.fk_idCategoria
```

Porém estou perdido ao organizar quando uma categoria possui mais de 1 produto, quando dou `print_r($var)` exibe o seguinte:

CATEGORIA 1

```
- Produto 1
```

CATEGORIA 2

```
- Produto 1
```

CATEGORIA 2

```
- Produto 2
```

Alguém poderia me dar uma luz ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pra trazer em uma linha só, você pode usar o `GROUP_CONCAT`  e usar um delimitador para retornar os produtos. o Padrão é vir da maneira que está vindo mesmo, se você tivesse 10 produtos para a mesma categoria, vai retornar 10x a mesma categoria e os produtos diferentes, porém se usar o `GROUP_CONCAT` você retornar apenas 1 vez a categoria e os produtos separados por um delimitador a sua escolha, não entendi se é isso mesmo que precisa, mas seria assim:

```
$sql = "SELECT 
            c.*,
            p.*,
            GROUP_CONCAT([produto] SEPARATOR ',') AS produtos
        FROM categorias c 
        INNER JOIN produtos p ON categorias.id = produtos.fk_idCategoria
        GROUP BY c.id";
```

Onde [produto] é o nome do campo da sua tabela  produtos e a ',' é o separador que você deseja.

Comment: Olá, primeiramente obrigado. Esqueci de mencionar, eu preciso acessar outras colunas do produto, por exemplo PRODUTO 1, preciso acessar o preço, a descrição etc. Dessa maneira que vc mencionou, eu só consigo retornar uma coluna que seria o [produto], correto ?

Comment: consegue sim, editei a resposta

Comment: Obrigado arrllondias, resolveu meu problema.

Comment: De nada @Jonas.

Answer (score 0):

**Apenas ordenar pela categoria**

Se você quer apenas mostrar primeiro todos os dados dos produtos da categoria X e depois da Y e assim por diante, pode fazer um select simples com order by

```
SELECT * FROM produdo ORDER BY fk_idCategoria
```

**Dividir por categoria**

Mas se você quer fazer uma divisão por categoria, por exemplo, criar uma tabela por categoria você pode (além do comando a cima) criar o início de uma tabela e, ao fazer o loop para buscar os dados do banco, verificar se o id da categoria mudou, no caso fecha a tabela atual e abre outra, [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/286209/criar-relat%C3%B3rio-exibindo-total-e-subtotal/287075#287075) tem uma resposta que faz isso

Answer (score -1):

Já tentou ordenar a sua query por Id da categoria?

```
$var = '
    SELECT * 
    FROM categorias 
    INNER JOIN produtos ON categorias.id = produtos.fk_idCategoria 
    ORDER BY produtos.fk_idCategoria
';
```

Dessa forma provávelmente o seu `print_r` retornará algo mais próximo do que você precisa, porém será necessário controlar como exibir os dados com testes lógicos e estruturas de repetições.