# Ordenar colunas conforme categoria

Tags: php, query

Preciso selecionar e deixar tudo organizado conforme a sua categoria:

Um exemplo: https://novaframework.com/documentation/v2.2

Minha tabela está assim:

Categorias:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Artigos:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Minha query:

```
$query = "
    SELECT 
c.*,
a.*,
GROUP_CONCAT(a.title SEPARATOR '|') AS articles
FROM categories c
INNER JOIN articles a ON c.category_id = a.category_id
GROUP BY c.category_id";
```

Com essa query à cima acaba que ficando assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Não entendi muito bem o que você quer fazer, mas se for pra selecionar todos os artigos por ordem de categoria basta um: SELECT * FROM artigos ORDER BY category_id

Comment: @JoãoBolsson, eu preciso retornar cada artigo dentro da sua id, repare que em categories, tem, começando, o basico e helpers vou editar o tópico com a minha query

Comment: Dá uma olhada nesse tópico: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/293484/exibir-produtos-de-v%C3%A1rias-categorias é o que você precisa